# Map is a namespace but is used like a type in Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am following the tutorial in https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/customized-pin/ to Creating the Custom Map, it works well when I am running the sample, but when it comes to my project. It has the error "Map is a namespace but is used like a type"
Here is my code:

```
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;

 namespace CapstoneProject.Map.Models
 {
     public class CustomMap: Map
     {
        public List<CustomPin> CustomPins { get; set; }
     }
 }
```

this code using Xamarin.Forms.Maps; is gray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like one part of your namespace has the word "Map". I'm guessing Xamarin Forms is confusing CapstoneProject.Map with Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Map.

If you have not gone too far with the sample, I would recommend starting again and not using "Map" in your naming structure.